# Set static Laravel URL to domain name I purchased

Tags: php, apache, laravel, dns

I need to set my url for my site to appear as mydomain.com/ and have apache recognize that as the webroot.

Currently my url looks like:
**###.###.##.##/laravel/public**

and I want it to become:
**mydomain.com/**

This is the first site I've worked on from scratch, so I'm not completely sure what information I should include here.

Current apache httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
(e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
SSL protocol.

VirtualHost example:
Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
server name.

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/foo_bar/public
    ServerName foo.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
 <Directory /var/www/html/foo/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
 </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Google 'apache httpd.conf' or 'apache server configuration' -- you should be able to find plenty of sample files and walkthroughs on how to set up your server.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to edit your `httpd.conf` (usually located somewhere like `/etc/apache2/conf`).

Look for a line like `<Directory "/var/www">`. This is telling apache the root directory from which you want to work. `/var/www` in your case will be whatever directory `laravel/public` is living in on your websever currently.

If you change that line to `<Directory "/var/www/laravel/public">` (assuming `/var/www` is where your laravel app is), save the file and restart apache, then you should be serving `mydomain.com` from inside `laravel/public`.